# How do I give focus to a python Tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, text, widget, tkinter

I'd like to be able to open the App GUI and have it automatically place the cursor into a particular text widget. Best case scenario is: as soon as the app is launched someone can start typing without having to click on the text widget. This is just a small example displaying the issue:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Window = Frame(root)
TextWidget = Text(Window)
TextWidget.pack()
Window.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You use the `focus_set` method. For example:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Window = Frame(root)
TextWidget = Text(Window)
TextWidget.pack()
Window.pack()
TextWidget.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, I can't believe I missed it :). Thanks.